# trying to use currentTarget for mouseEvent

Tags: javascript, flash, jquery-animate, adobe

I'm using Adobe Animate for a project and I have an array of movieclips with event listeners attached to them. I'm trying to figure out a way to find out which movieclip was clicked on and respond accordingly. My listener function looks like this:

```
function navigationControls(e){

console.log(e)

switch(e.currentTarget){
    case lib.dayOneBtn:
        console.log("add day 1");
        break;

    case lib.dayTwoBtn:
        console.log("add day 2");
        break;

    case "lib.dayThreeBtn":
        console.log("add day 3");
        break;
}
}
```

```
//--> console log {type: "click", target: a, currentTarget: lib.dayOneBtn, eventPhase: 3, bubbles: true…}
```

When I console.log the e.currentTarget, I can see the Linkage of the movieclip from the library, but I'm not sure what property to use in the switch statement. lib.(Linkage name) isn't working.

I was able to get this working by checking against the movieclip on the state, and not in the array. Here is the updated code:

```
case navContainer.dayOneBtn:
        console.log("add day 1");
        break;

    case navContainer.dayTwoBtn:
        console.log("add day 2");
        break;

    case navContainer.dayThreeBtn:
        console.log("add day 3");
        break;
}
```

Comment: What is `lib`? Please provide a [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: lib is a reference of the library in Adobe Animate CC.

Comment: try the linkage name only...?

Answer (score 0):

If these are movieclips you could switch on the .name property (the linkage name). Just assign one to each MC on creation:

```
dayOneButton = new DayMC();
dayOneButton.name = "dayOne";

dayTwoButton = new DayMC();
dayTwoButton.name = "dayTwo";

function navigationControls(e:Event)
{
    var clickedMC:MovieClip = e.currentTarget as MovieClip;

    switch(clickedMC.name)
    {
       case "dayOne":
           // do stuff
           break;
    }
}
```